# WPF- positioning buttons on a Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, layout

I am integrating a `WebKitBrowser` into a C# application, using WPF to implement the GUI for the application.

Having just added 'tabbed viewing' functionality to the application (where the user can select one tab to view the application, and another tab to view a web browser inside the application window), I now want to add navigation buttons to the form, similar to that of a standard web browser (i.e. 'Back', 'Forward' & 'Refresh' buttons).

I have the following markup in my `.xaml` file:

```
<Grid>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Background="White">
        ...
        <Ribbon x:Name="NavMenu" SelectedIndex="0" Width="928" Height="30">
            <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="...\navigateBack.png" Height="5" Width="5" />
        </Ribbon>
    </Menu>
    <TabControl agent="clr-namespace:Agent" Margin="0,29,-0.4,0.4">
        <TabItem Header="Application">
            ...
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Browser">
            ...
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

However, when I run my application, although I can see the 'menu' `Ribbon` that I have added (alongside the application `MainMenu`, and above the `TabControl`), the button that I have added to the ribbon seems to be quite 'low' (i.e. it is displayed behind the 'tab' controls), so I can only see the top of the button.

In the Design view in Visual Studio, I can see that the ribbon is displayed at the same height as the `MainMenu`, so its contents should be displayed above the tabs, but at the moment, the button that I have added to the ribbon is being displayed behind the tabs...

Is there a way that I can set the position of the button on the ribbon, so that it is bound to the top of the ribbon, so that the whole button will be shown above the tabs?

I have tried looking for a `position` or `x` & `y` attributes that I can set on the `<RibbonButton />` tag in XAML, but can't seem to find anything that does what I want here- anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The more canonical way of laying this out would be as follows (which may correct the issue)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Background="White">
        ...
        <Ribbon x:Name="NavMenu" SelectedIndex="0">
            <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="...\navigateBack.png"  />
        </Ribbon>
    </Menu>
    <TabControl agent="clr-namespace:Agent" Margin="0,0,-0.4,0.4" Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Application">
            ...
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Browser">
            ...
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion- I've given this a go, but when I run the application, it displays in exactly the same way as it was with what I'd written- i.e. the button displayed behind the tabs...

Comment: Did you change the margins as in my example ?

Comment: I decided in the end, that rather than adding the navigation controls to the main application window, I would add them to each individual tab, as it is likely that I will need different navigation controls depending on which tab is displayed... As such, I am no longer using the `Ribbon`, but just using standard `Button`s and a `ComboBox` as the navigation controls inside the `<Grid></Grid>` tags